# SQL Server transaction (ID) Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I'm facing a problem i can't solve while creating New database thru private software installation.

[image: Deadlock error image]

link to XML file of the trace tracking the deadlock [XML File here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=88580988908011733354)

i was able to track what causing the deadlock and its while i try to change db owner.

statement: EXEC [ISC_RAS_CD_APP].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false

[image]

```xml
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock
        victim="process4efa404e8">
        <process-list>
            <process
                id="process4efa404e8"
                taskpriority="0"
                logused="0"
                waitresource="KEY: 1:281474978545664 (11ea04af99f6)"
                waittime="4947"
                ownerId="1284191"
                transactionname="HkHostCkptEnableDisable"
                lasttranstarted="2017-02-23T12:51:54.617"
                XDES="0x4ff1e5be0"
                lockMode="S"
                schedulerid="4"
                kpid="10252"
                status="suspended"
                spid="62"
                sbid="0"
                ecid="0"
                priority="0"
                trancount="1"
                lastbatchstarted="2017-02-23T12:51:54.610"
                lastbatchcompleted="2017-02-23T12:51:54.610"
                lastattention="2017-02-23T12:51:54.580"
                clientapp="SQL Management"
                hostname="IDQSRV01"
                hostpid="8940"
                loginname="HMS\OrenG"
                isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                xactid="1284156"
                currentdb="12"
                lockTimeout="4294967295"
                clientoption1="673185824"
                clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame
                        procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_changedbowner"
                        line="26"
                        stmtstart="1656"
                        stmtend="1686"
                        sqlhandle="0x0300ff7f12d71ceed5d2350180a4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
checkpoint     </frame>
                    <frame
                        procname="adhoc"
                        line="1"
                        sqlhandle="0x01000c0069b98f048084f3000500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC [ISC_RAS_CD_APP].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
EXEC [ISC_RAS_CD_APP].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false    </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <keylock
                hobtid="281474978545664"
                dbid="1"
                objectname="master.sys.sysdbreg"
                indexname="clst"
                id="lock5006efc00"
                mode="X"
                associatedObjectId="281474978545664">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner
                        id="process4efa404e8"
                        mode="X" />
                    <owner
                        id="process4efa404e8"
                        mode="S"
                        requestType="wait" />
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter
                        id="process4efa404e8"
                        mode="S"
                        requestType="wait" />
                </waiter-list>
            </keylock>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

"sa" is a default user which i created while installing the new server.

my task priority is set to 0 but everytime it gives me a different task ID so im not sure if i can change it.

i was looking at every single answer online but nothing could help me,anyone has an idea what i can do to fix it?

further information can be supplied if needed.

Regards

Comment: you will need to add deadlock graph

Comment: @MartinSmith How do i do that?

Comment: In profiler right click and I think the option is called extract event info to save it as an XML file - then you can paste it into your question

Comment: @MartinSmith xml file was now added . thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange graph. The session is deadlocked  waiting for a resource that the session owns itself.

You provided the Profiler trace not just the deadlock graph.

Based on that I can reproduce the problem on 2014 but not 2012 or 2016.

Code that reproduces the issue for me on all 2014 instances I have tested (with builds as below)

- (SP1-CU9-GDR) (KB3194722) - 12.0.4487.0 (X64)
- (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64))
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU4) (KB4010394) - 12.0.5540.0 (X64)

```
IF db_id('FOO') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
print 'dropping db'
use master
alter database [FOO] set single_user with rollback immediate
drop database [FOO]
END

go

CREATE DATABASE [FOO]
go

BEGIN TRANSACTION
use [FOO]
EXEC [FOO].dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false
COMMIT
```

I assume the `Hk` in the `HkHostCkptEnableDisable` (transaction name in the deadlock graph) refers to "Hekaton" so maybe this was an issue introduced with some code change to support in memory OLTP in 2014.

The problem goes away if I get rid of the explicit transaction. So one approach would be to do that to release the lock that is being contested.

Or alternatively you can follow the advice in the deprecation notice for [`sp_changedbowner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx)

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION instead.

`sp_changedbowner` calls this anyway but adds an additional `checkpoint` that causes the problem (I also get the deadlock if I use the code below with the checkpoint line uncommented).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
alter authorization on database::[FOO] to [sa]
--checkpoint
COMMIT
```

The checkpoint seems to cause a read to the same row in `master.sys.sysdbreg` that is exclusively locked by the `alter authorization` within the same session earlier (the `sid` column gets updated to `0x01` for the row belonging to this database) and the checkpoint transaction is unable to get the lock granted to the user transaction.